# Horizontal spaces before and after inline math inside theorem-like environments are unbalanced

Tags: math-mode, theorems

Horizontal space inserted before an inline math expression is relatively narrow compared to the "after" counterpart. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
 For any $n \times n$ square matrix $M$ over a commutative ring $R$, its determinant
 $\mathrm{det}(M)$ is defined as follows:
 \[
  \mathrm{det}(M) =
  \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\left(\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i, \sigma(i)} \right).
 \]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

And here is the problematic part of the output:

[image: the space before "M" is narrow compared to the space after "M"]

I guess this is related to the fact that both theorem-like environments and math expressions use italic font (slanted type). If an inline math expression (which is slanted) appears in the middle of upright text, inserting more space after the math expression seems to make sense. How can I fix this spacing issue once and for all?

Comment: Unrelated use `\det` not `\mathrm{det}`

Comment: Use an italic correction: `For any\/ $n \times n$ square matrix\/ $M$ over a commutative ring\/ $R$`...

Answer (score 2):

When you switch to the Unicode math Latin Modern font, then your problem disappears. I tried this by OpTeX:

```
{\it matrix $M$ over} ... 7bit fonts

\fontfam[lm]

{\it matrix $M$ over} ... Unicode math

\bye
```

result:

[image: M over]

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for the answer, and that's very good to know! But, does that mean I can no longer use pdfLaTeX? For writing research papers, I'm often forced to use pdfLaTeX. So alternative solutions would still be useful.

Comment: @KazuhikoSakaguchi If you are using LaTeX macro package then Unicode math is available in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. IMHO, pdfLaTeX is many years obsolete and there is no reason to use it. If somebody forced you to use this obsolete software then he must compromise on aestetic requirements.